# Renaming remaining properties variable when object destructuring in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

> **EDIT:**
>
> I opened an issue related to this on github:
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21265
>   It seems that `{ ...other: xother }` is not valid JS, neither TS, code and it should not even compile.

**Original question:**

Let's assume the following example:

```
const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" };
const { a: va, b: vb, ...other } = values;
```

where a new variable name `va` is assigned for property `a`.

Is it valid, according to TypeScript specs, to do the same with the remaining properties `...other`? Something like:

```
const { a: va, b: vb, ...other: vother } = values;
```

I know it works, I've tested it ([online test](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20values%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%221%22%2C%20b%3A%20%222%22%2C%20c%3A%20%223%22%2C%20d%3A%20%224%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%3A%20va%2C%20b%3A%20vb%2C%20...vother%20%7D%20%3D%20values%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(va%2C%20vb%2C%20vother)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22----%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20a%3A%20xa%2C%20b%3A%20xb%2C%20...other%3A%20xother%20%7D%20%3D%20values%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(xa%2C%20xb%2C%20xother)%3B%0D%0A)). But I'm unable to find where it's defined to do so.

The examples of the documents that refers to property renaming always show the "normal" case: [TypeScript Handbook - Variable Declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html). And the spec grammar refres to a `BindingPattern` that's no described (or I've missed) in the spec: [TypeScript Spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf).

My first impression is that it is not very useful since `...other` is already a custom variable name. But it works. And I'm curious to know where it is specifically defined or if it's only a corner case that works (I suppose not).

Comment: You are referring to Rest/Spread Properties which are not official part of  ECMAScript yet but still just a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) ([specification](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-object-rest-spread/)).

Answer (score 14):

The handbook link you mention covers most of the scenarios you have in your example under [destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring), but I think the one situation it covers is not explicitly covered (only implicitly).

The particular feature you are referring to (I think) is the combination of:

> You can create a variable for the remaining items in an object using the syntax `...`:

and

> You can also give different names to properties:

The handbook doesn't give an example where both are used, as shown below. The interesting part of this combined use is that the `...other` token doesn't actually mean anything and is never referenced (or referenceable). In the "working" version of the below example, without the erroring line, the `other` token doesn't appear in the output at all.

Here is the shortened example:

```
const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" };

const { a: one, ...other: twoThreeFour } = values;

console.log(other); // ERROR there is no variable 'other'
console.log(a, twoThreeFour); // OK
```

And the version without the error - the transpiled JavaScript has no reference to `other` anywhere in the code:

```
const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" };

const { a: one, ...other: twoThreeFour } = values;

console.log(a, twoThreeFour); // OK
```

There is an [issue to improve the clarity of the use of rest elements in relation to destructuring](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2713) in the underlying language specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can give any other name than `other` when destructuring variables. For example:

```
const {...rest} = someVaribale;
const {...myname} = otherVariable;
```